# Parsing an Object with Functions

Tags: javascript, json, function, parsing

```js
var Car = function(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;

    this.print = function() {
        console.log(name+" "+year);
    }
}

var tesla = new Car("tesla", 2018);
tesla.print();
tesla = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tesla));
console.log(tesla);
tesla.print(); // Uncaught TypeError: tesla.print is not a function
```

How can i add the print function to the object after the parse? Is there an elegant solution for this?

Comment: The *value* in a JSON string can only be a string, number, bool, object, array or null (https://www.json.org/). All the function keys are stripped by `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` doesn't handle functions... so they just get removed... So you're pretty much 'deleting' your function print.

Comment: You can't. A JSON with a `function()` is not a JSON but a Javascript Object. The real question is, why do you need to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tesla))` in the first place? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Once you run JSON.stringify(), you change the instance of `tesla`, borrowing back the print function from the car can be a solution or make a difference in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) for printing and call the method with an object for binding.

```js
function Car(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
}

Car.prototype.print = function() {            // add prototype
    console.log(this.name + " " + this.year); // take this as reference to the instance
};

var tesla = new Car("tesla", 2018);
tesla.print();
tesla = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tesla));
console.log(tesla);
Car.prototype.print.call(tesla);              // borrow method from class, take own object
```

A clean approach is to add a function `deserialize` as prototype which takes an object and assign all properties to the instance.

```js
function Car(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
}

Car.prototype.print = function() {
    console.log(this.name + " " + this.year);
};

Car.prototype.deserialize = function(object) {
    Object.entries(object).forEach(([k, v]) => this[k] = v);
};

var tesla = new Car("tesla", 2018);
tesla.print();
tesla = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tesla));
console.log(tesla);
var tesla2 = new Car;
tesla2.deserialize(tesla);
tesla2.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON data format does not support functions (which would be very unhelpful if you generated some JSON from a JavaScript object and then tried to parse it with C#!).

A sensible approach to this would be to change the `Car` constructor function so that it can accept an object as the first argument.

```
var Car = function(name, year) {
    if (typeof name === "object") {
        // use properties of `name` to set everything in this object
    } else {
        // Treat name and year as a string and number just like you are now
    }
    ...
```

Then you can:

```
tesla = new Car( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tesla)) );
```

… which will also generate an object with the correct prototype.